# EF5.x Adding Custom Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am using EF5.x Code First

```
namespace DAO.Models
{
    public partial class Person
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
}
}
```

i created another partial class to add custom properties.

```
namespace DAO.Models
{
    public partial class Person
    {
        public string customName { get; set; }
}
}
```

I have a Mapping that has been generated for my by EF 5.x power tools

```
    public PersonMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.PersonId });


        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Person", "TableX");
        this.Property(t => t.PersonId).HasColumnName("PersonId");


    }
```

when i try to add a new person to db

```
 XContext db = new XContext();

                Person per= new Person();
   db.Persons.Add(per);
```

**I get unknown column customName in Field List error**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [[NotMapped]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx) annotation/attribute

```
[NotMapped]
public string customName { get; set; }
```